# Malformed entry in apt sources list on Ubuntu system

Tags: ubuntu, apt

[image]

Every time I am trying to install something it shows me this error, please help as I am new to Linux based OS
contents in /etc/apt/sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210819)]/ focal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
deb http://www.geogebra.net/linux/stable main
# deb-src http://www.geogebra.net/linux/stable main
deb http://www.geogebra.net/linux/pool/main/g/geogebra-classic/ focal
# deb-src http://www.geogebra.net/linux/pool/main/g/geogebra-classic/ focal
```

Comment: here are different ways to restore default repository https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories

Comment: Next time, please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397).

Comment: You also appear to be using two different accounts. [Please merge them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) - otherwise you're going to have difficulty editing your question to add more information, and you won't be able to accept the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

The correct repository is:

```
deb http://www.geogebra.net/linux/ stable main
```

To fix your `sources.list`:

```
sudo sed -i '/geogebra/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

to cleanly add `geogebra` repository:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C072A32983A736CF
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://www.geogebra.net/linux/ stable main"
sudo apt update
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments saying that you shouldn't post pictures of text, and the one suggesting you merge your accounts.

It's a really simple question, and the error message basically says where the error is, line 58 of `sources.list`, which is

```
deb http://www.geogebra.net/linux/stable main
```

I haven't tried installing geogebra, so I don't know for sure what a correct line should lok like, but my guess is that you should replace the last `/` (i.e. the one between `linux` and `stable`) with a space.

Line 60 in `sources.list` have the same problem, my instinct for that is to delete the line (but as I said, I haven't tried to install gegebra).

Comment: Right, the ending slash selects the alternate syntax that takes one less parameter (no suite).